# I want to trigger the text using mouseover in cypress with javascript?

Tags: automation, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

```
cy.xpath("(//[local-name()='svg']//[name()='g' and @data-z-index='8'])[1]//*[name()='text']").wait(300)
.trigger('mouseover', { force: true }).then(($text1) => {
        var textValue2 = $text1.text()
        cy.log(textValue2)
})
```

This is code I'm using triggering to perform mouseover to get the text
facing error not finding the element showing "Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find element: (//[local-name()='svg']//[name()='g' and @data-z-index='8'])[1]//*[name()='text'], but never found it."

**Note**: But the xpath is correct, If I manually hover then retrieve the text.

Comment: If you try to do some other action on the element (click, assert text value, etc.), is it successful? Or does it still say that it can't find the element. My initial guess is that your xpath is not correct, and if other actions do not work, then that is probably the case.

Answer (score 0):

Use trigger('mouseenter') it should works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: trigger('mouseenter')  is not working.....